# What could possibly be wrong with this query in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

This query

```
UPDATE `sites_configuration` SET `configuration_value`= `value` 
WHERE `configuration_id` = 41 AND `sites_id` = 2 LIMIT 0, 30
```

gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 30' at line 1
```

What syntax error is it referring to? I tried putting a semicolon or wrapping the statement in quotation marks, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`LIMIT 0,30` does not make sense in an update query. Try `LIMIT 30`.

Comment: Why does it not make sense? Please provide more information with your answer.

Comment: try "limit 30" instead of "limit 0,30"

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html) you can only give a rowcount in Limit not the offset.

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] tbl_name
    SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Cange you query to

```
UPDATE `sites_configuration` SET `configuration_value`= `value` 
WHERE `configuration_id` = 41 AND `sites_id` = 2 LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not specify limit ofset with update its invalid

Wrong : limit 0,10

However you can specify as

```
update table set val = 'something' limit 30
```

Here is a demo

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------------+--------+--------+
| Date       | Person | Action |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2014-01-01 | John   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-01 | lilly  | Enter  |
| 2014-01-01 | bill   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-01 | bill   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | bill   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | lilly  | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | bill   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | John   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | John   | Enter  |
+------------+--------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> update test set Action = 'GO' limit 0,5;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5' at line 1

mysql> update test set Action = 'GO' limit 5;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------------+--------+--------+
| Date       | Person | Action |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2014-01-01 | John   | GO     |
| 2014-01-01 | lilly  | GO     |
| 2014-01-01 | bill   | GO     |
| 2014-01-01 | bill   | GO     |
| 2014-01-02 | bill   | GO     |
| 2014-01-02 | lilly  | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | bill   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | John   | Enter  |
| 2014-01-02 | John   | Enter  |
+------------+--------+--------+
```